# C++ - Access violoation when calling .clear() of std::vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, stdvector, access-violation

I am implementing an XLSX spreadsheet Reader in Visual Studio C++ MFC app and am getting an access violation error when executing it multiple times:

```
First-chance exception at 0x7720e39e in VCT.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x02bdddab.
Unhandled exception at 0x7720e39e in VCT.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x02bdddab.
The program '[1756] VCT.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

The weird thing is that depending on the rest of my code, this can occur after the function being called twice, three times, or more... This makes me think that it has something to do with timing, but I only have the single thread running. Another one of my (more realistic) hypotheses is that it is an undefined behavior. This makes it especially difficult to debug. What confuses me is why this access violation would happen after multiple calls to the function.

**Added to question:**

I call the function `getVectorAllIP` every time a button is clicked. After a few clicks (calls to `getVectorAllIP`), the I get the access violation error on the first call to `mm_XLSXReader.xlsxGetCellOffset`.

```
vector<CString> CVCTDlg::getVectorAllIP(string ipName){

    CString CSIP1;

    vector<CString> VCSIPAddresses;

    XLSXReader mm_XLSXReader;
    mm_XLSXReader.reloadFile();
    mm_XLSXReader.setFilePath(XLSX_FILE_PATH);

    for(int i = 0; i < m_vectorStrHostname.size(); i++)
    {
        CSIP1="";
        for(int iOffset = 0; iOffset < 4; iOffset++)
        {

            CSIP1.Append(mm_XLSXReader.xlsxGetCellOffset(ipName, i, iOffset).c_str());
            if(iOffset != 3)
            {
                CSIP1.Append(".");
            }
        }

        if(CSIP1 != "...")
        {

            VCSIPAddresses.push_back(CSIP1);

        }else{
            VCSIPAddresses.push_back("");
        }

    }

    return VCSIPAddresses;

}
```

Within `xlsxGetCellOffset`, the access violation error occurs within `readSheetXml`.

```
string XLSXReader::xlsxGetCellOffset(string columnName, int id, int offset)
{
    string contentToReturn;
    id++;

    if(!m_bFileInMemory)
    {
        if(openm_XLSXReader())
        {
            readSharedStringsXml();
            readSheetXml();

            closem_XLSXReaders();

            m_bFileInMemory = true;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < m_header.size(); i++)
    {
        if(m_header.at(i) == columnName && m_header.size() > i + offset)
        {
            if(m_sheetContent.size() > id)
            {
                if(m_sheetContent.at(id).size() > i)
                {
                    contentToReturn = m_sheetContent.at(id).at(i+offset);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return contentToReturn;
}
```

The access violation occurs during the clearing sequence at the end. Specifically at the `columnContent.clear()`. If I remove `columnContent.clear()` it occurs at the next line `tParameterColumn.clear()`.

```
void XLSXReader::readSheetXml()
{
    if(m_m_XLSXReader)
    {
        int error = unzLocateFile(m_m_XLSXReader, SHEET_NAME, 0);
        if(error == UNZ_OK)
        {
            error = unzOpenCurrentFile(m_m_XLSXReader);
            if(error == UNZ_OK)
            {
                int readingStatus = 0;
                char readBuffer[BUFFERSIZE];
                string file;
                int indexValue;
                //Reading File
                do
                {
                    readingStatus = unzReadCurrentFile(m_m_XLSXReader, readBuffer, BUFFERSIZE);
                    file.append(readBuffer, readingStatus);
                }while(readingStatus > 0);


                //Sort Data
                vector<string> rowContent;
                rowContent = findXmlTagsContent(file, "row");

                unsigned int iHdrSize;
                m_header.clear();

                vector<string> columnContent;
                vector<string> tParameterColumn;
                vector<string> rParameterColumn;
                vector<string> tmpRow;
                for(int i = 0 ; i < rowContent.size(); i++)
                {

                    columnContent=findXmlTagsContent( rowContent.at(i), "c"); 
                    rParameterColumn=findXmlParameterInTag(rowContent.at(i), "c", "r");
                    tParameterColumn=findXmlParameterInTag(rowContent.at(i), "c", "t");
                    if(i==0){
                        iHdrSize = columnContent.size();
                    }

                    //Should be equal
                    if(columnContent.size() == tParameterColumn.size())
                    {
                        unsigned int iFilledColumns = 0;
                        for(int j = 0 ; j < columnContent.size(); j++)
                        {               

                            int columnNumber = 0;

                            if(!rParameterColumn.at(j).empty())
                            {
                                columnNumber = columnLetter2Int(rParameterColumn.at(j));
                            }

                            vector<string> value;
                            value = findXmlTagsContent(columnContent.at(j), "v");

                            if(value.size()>1){
                                value.clear();
                                value.push_back("");
                            }

                            //Header Reading
                            if( i == 0)
                            {
                                //Fill empty spaces in excel sheet with ""
                                for(int a = 1; a < columnNumber-iFilledColumns; a++)
                                {
                                    m_header.push_back("");
                                }
                                iFilledColumns=m_header.size();

                                //link to sharedString
                                if(tParameterColumn.at(j) == "s")
                                {
                                    indexValue = atoi(value.at(0).c_str());
                                    string tmpStr = m_sharedString.at(indexValue);
                                    m_header.push_back(tmpStr);
                                }
                                //Value
                                else
                                {   
                                    m_header.push_back(value.at(0));
                                }
                            }
                            // Content Reading
                            else
                            {
                                ////Fill empty spaces in excel sheet with ""
                                for(int a = 1; a < columnNumber-iFilledColumns; a++)
                                {
                                    tmpRow.push_back("");
                                }
                                iFilledColumns=tmpRow.size();
                                //link to sharedString

                                if(tParameterColumn.at(j) == "s")
                                {
                                    indexValue = atoi(value.at(0).c_str());
                                    tmpRow.push_back(m_sharedString.at(indexValue));
                                }
                                //Value
                                else
                                {
                                    if(value.size() != 0)
                                    {
                                        tmpRow.push_back(value.at(value.size()-1));
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        tmpRow.push_back("");
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            iFilledColumns++;
                        }
                        for(int k=0;k<iHdrSize-iFilledColumns;k++){
                            tmpRow.push_back("");
                        }
                        m_sheetContent.push_back(tmpRow);
                        tmpRow.clear();
                        columnContent.clear();
                        tParameterColumn.clear();
                        rParameterColumn.clear();

                    }
                }       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And just FYI, the `m_m_XLSXReader` is instantiated on a call to `openm_XLSXReader` called within `xlsxGetCellOffset`. Here it is for your reference:

```
bool XLSXReader::openm_XLSXReader()
{
    //Uncompress .xlsx
    m_m_XLSXReader = unzOpen(m_strXLSXPath.c_str());

    if(m_m_XLSXReader){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope someone can point out some glaring obvious mistake, because I am starting to question my sanity :) Thanks.

Comment: That entire `XLSXReader` object could be invalid, thus making any operation within it a cause of undefined behavior.  Show us where, when, and how you instantiate this (these) object(s).  Also `if (m_m_XLSXReader)` -- what if this test is faulty (erroneously returns `true`), thus you get thrust into code that should never have executed?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added the calling sequence to the question. Can you take another look?

Comment: So which error are you getting - `allocation` or `access violation`?

Comment: @VladFeinstein Access violation. Sorry for the mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: Could you please clarify your statement `"access violation appears to occur"`? Don't you know for sure? When that exception is caught, could you break into debugger and see the content of your `columnContent`? If the vector is corrupted, it means that your wrote outside of the boundaries somewhere. I would expect all standard vector and strings to behave correctly. What is the type of `m_sheetContent`? Is it `vector<vector<string>>`? Then the only suspect is your readBuffer.

Comment: @VladFeinstein I used the term appears, because when `columnContent.clear()` is present, the `access violation` occurs there. But if I remove it, then it occurs on the next line, `tParameterColumn.clear()`. `m_SheetContent` is a `vector<vector<string>>`. Through breakpoints I don't see any difference in `columnContent` before a successful or `access violation` `.clear()`. In the case that the access violation does occur, through the debugger I can see that the `.clear()` only makes it to halfway of the `columnContent` vector before the crash.

Comment: Let me make some assumptions: (1) The uncorrupt vector of strings will not cause access violation when `clear()` is called; (2) Since all your vectors are local variables (located on the stack), one of the functions called there has corrupted the stack; (3) None of the `std::` functions corrupted the stack.   If you agree with that, I would take a closer look into your xml functions `findXmlTagsContent()`, `findXmlParameterInTag()` and `columnLetter2Int()` to see if they may overwrite the stack.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Thank you for those assumptions. I agree with them. I did however discover something interesting. I ran a loop that ran `getVectorAllIP` 100 times, and i didn't get a crash. This leads me to think that the issue that is screwing up the stack is somewhere around `getVectorAllIP`. I am exploring this now.

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
do
{
    readingStatus = unzReadCurrentFile(m_m_XLSXReader, readBuffer, BUFFERSIZE);
    file.append(readBuffer, readingStatus);
} while (readingStatus > 0);
```

will append the last read block twice, most likely producing invalid XML.
I don't know which library you use to read XML (can't find any references to `findXmlTagsContent` other than this question), and how resilient it is, but suspect it may not behave well being fed garbage. Plus, you are not checking for any possible errors...

Bottom line is: try reading your file like this:

```
while ((readingStatus = unzReadCurrentFile(m_m_XLSXReader, readBuffer, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0)
    file.append(readBuffer, readingStatus);
```

Also, what are you going to do if the return is negative (an error code)?

Comment: I tried to reading like that but I'm still getting the crash... So I don't think that is the reason.  I agree with you that I need to handle the case of an error code, so I will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So thank you all for your help and suggestions.

Vlad, your suggestions really got me thinking in a more logical way and then I found the problem which was completely unrelated to the actual XLSX reading.

The simple explanation is that when I click the button that sets off the XLSX reader, I modify the windows registry before that. In the process of recursively removing some registry keys, some sort of memory corruption occurs, that was only reflected when I got the access violation. I fixed my registry code, and now the issue is has been resolved.

If anyone is interested about the actual issue regarding recursively deleting registry keys, keep reading...

I was using the code to recursively delete a registry key and its subkeys:

[Deleting a Key with Subkeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724235(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

//*************************************************************
//
//  RegDelnodeRecurse()
//
//  Purpose:    Deletes a registry key and all its subkeys / values.
//
//  Parameters: hKeyRoot    -   Root key
//              lpSubKey    -   SubKey to delete
//
//  Return:     TRUE if successful.
//              FALSE if an error occurs.
//
//*************************************************************

BOOL RegDelnodeRecurse (HKEY hKeyRoot, LPTSTR lpSubKey)
{
    LPTSTR lpEnd;
    LONG lResult;
    DWORD dwSize;
    TCHAR szName[MAX_PATH];
    HKEY hKey;
    FILETIME ftWrite;

    // First, see if we can delete the key without having
    // to recurse.

    lResult = RegDeleteKey(hKeyRoot, lpSubKey);

    if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
        return TRUE;

    lResult = RegOpenKeyEx (hKeyRoot, lpSubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
    {
        if (lResult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            printf("Key not found.\n");
            return TRUE;
        } 
        else {
            printf("Error opening key.\n");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Check for an ending slash and add one if it is missing.

    lpEnd = lpSubKey + lstrlen(lpSubKey);

    if (*(lpEnd - 1) != TEXT('\\')) 
    {
        *lpEnd =  TEXT('\\');
        lpEnd++;
        *lpEnd =  TEXT('\0');
    }

    // Enumerate the keys

    dwSize = MAX_PATH;
    lResult = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, 0, szName, &dwSize, NULL,
                           NULL, NULL, &ftWrite);

    if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
    {
        do {

            StringCchCopy (lpEnd, MAX_PATH*2, szName);

            if (!RegDelnodeRecurse(hKeyRoot, lpSubKey)) {
                break;
            }

            dwSize = MAX_PATH;

            lResult = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, 0, szName, &dwSize, NULL,
                                   NULL, NULL, &ftWrite);

        } while (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS);
    }

    lpEnd--;
    *lpEnd = TEXT('\0');

    RegCloseKey (hKey);

    // Try again to delete the key.

    lResult = RegDeleteKey(hKeyRoot, lpSubKey);

    if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}

//*************************************************************
//
//  RegDelnode()
//
//  Purpose:    Deletes a registry key and all its subkeys / values.
//
//  Parameters: hKeyRoot    -   Root key
//              lpSubKey    -   SubKey to delete
//
//  Return:     TRUE if successful.
//              FALSE if an error occurs.
//
//*************************************************************

BOOL RegDelnode (HKEY hKeyRoot, LPTSTR lpSubKey)
{
    TCHAR szDelKey[MAX_PATH*2];

    StringCchCopy (szDelKey, MAX_PATH*2, lpSubKey);
    return RegDelnodeRecurse(hKeyRoot, szDelKey);

}

void __cdecl main()
{
   BOOL bSuccess;

   bSuccess = RegDelnode(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\TestDir"));

   if(bSuccess)
      printf("Success!\n");
   else printf("Failure.\n");
}
```

If I had values in the key I was trying to delete, then everything worked as expected. In the case where I had a key with a subkey inside of it, they were deleted, but I began have the issues of my question above.

So for example this was deleted without causing me a life of pain,

```
[KeyName1]
--> SOME_DWORD
--> SOME_STRING
```

And this one caused me much pain indeed,

```
[KeyName2]
--> SOME_DWORD
--> SOME_STRING
--> [SubKeyName]
-----> SOME_DWORD
-----> SOME_STRING
```